# google mobile vision - get face matrix

Tags: android, mobile, detection, face-detection, vision

I started using the google mobile vision API.

I see from the [example given by google at:](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker) 
That it recognizes faces and gives their coordinates and landmarks, i.e eys, cheeks etc.

I want to use the coordinates given above, and crop out the entire face, meaning the whole matrix in the rect. I can't find a way to get the frame in the google mobile vision API.

Anyone got the answer?